# Ошибка при загрузке Ubuntu сразу после установки

Tags: linux, ubuntu

После успешной установки Ubuntu 20.10 и перезагрузки компьютера, сачала выдало вот такие ошибки:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потом просто завис логотип Ubuntu. Подскажите как быть, я вообще не шарю:(

Comment: А на Ctrl+Alt+F2 хотя бы реагирует?

Answer (score -1):

Ошибка на скрине связана с несовместимостью ядра системы и версии биоса, может быть вам нужно поставить версию Ubuntu посвежее той, у которой закончился [срок поддержки в июле 2021](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9_Ubuntu#%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8)? Может быть какое-то другое семейство дистрибутивов попробовать